# Changing The Default Days Off Sprint for Scrum Template Using TFS 2012 RTM

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, scrum

I install Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2012 RTM on `d:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0\` then create the `Redemption` project in my TFS.

How to change the default days off sprint for scrum template to `Thursday` and `Friday`?

Answer (score 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500408.aspx

**Export the common configuration**

```
witadmin exportcommonprocessconfig /collection:CollectionURL /p:ProjectName /f:"DirectoryPath\CommonConfiguration.xml"
```

**Edit the common configuration**

```
<Weekends>
  <DayOfWeek>Saturday</DayOfWeek>
  <DayOfWeek>Sunday</DayOfWeek>
</Weekends>
```

**Import the common configuration**

```
witadmin importcommonprocessconfig /collection:CollectionURL /p:ProjectName /f:"DirectoryPath\CommonConfiguration.xml"
```

If you want to make it the default for further team projects you create, you need to export the entire process template, updated it and update it.

Comment: Note: This is not currently possible on http://tfs.visualstudio.com as you can't customise the process template

Answer (score 0):

the solution can be found here http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2792800-burndown-chart-should-exclude-non-work-days

in the web environment of your tfs server, go to the gear in the top right corner. depending on your authentication you can see the settings tab, if you click it, you will see checkboxes in front of the days listed. default only weekdays are enabled.