# How to include weekends in tfs 2012 preview?

Tags: tfs

Im working with TFS 2012 preview and my sprints include work on weekends, however tfs preview doesn't include weekends in it's sprint calculation.
How can I include weekends?

Comment: FYI, it's no longer a preview.

Comment: great...so how do I include weekends?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing The Default Days Off Sprint for Scrum Template Using TFS 2012 RTM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094741/changing-the-default-days-off-sprint-for-scrum-template-using-tfs-2012-rtm)

Answer (score 1):

It is not currently possible to do this on Team Foundation Service (formally TFS Preview) as you are not able to customize the Process Template.

While the Product Team would love to provide this feature there is currently no time frame on implantation. This stems form the complexities in upgrading templates as the product moves forward and if you make changes they will no longer be able to upgrade it for you.

If you have an on-premises Team Foundation Server then you would be able to make this customization.

I would suggest that you make the request on: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com